# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what's wrong with my website since I last upgraded it to new version of PHP Melody: http://www.juraatmedia.com/

Is this some script issues or server issues? Please check and reply asap. Thanks

(I am using NetworkSolutions hosting, I don't know whether mySQL server is running or not. I tried opening phpmyadmin for the specified db, it's opening but when I am clicking on my db on the left, it's just loading and not showing anything. Does that suppose to mean that mysql is not running? I tried contact them via email but they said I have to call their technical team. This is happening since saturday, how come their server is down since 2 days)

Comment: Is your MySQL server running? Is it creating the socket in the specified place? Please update your question ASAP.

Comment: May be MySQL isnt running  on that machine , or it may be listening on a port other than the default 3306

Answer (score 1):

If your db config is looking to connect on localhost, change it to 127.0.0.1 (I know it's the same but it somehow it acts differently). I've had that problem before with an upgrade. Was getting that error changed the hostname to an ip address solved my problem